# Здравствуйте, не могу удалить сообщение пользователя, Aiogram

Tags: aiogram

не могу удалить сообщение пользователя, подскажите пожалуйста

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['sms'],commands_prefix='-')
async def sms(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.message_id)
    await message.answer("️Удалено")
```

Comment: Если вам подошёл ответ примите его иначе на ваши вопросы желания отвечать не будет

Comment: Это надо галочку поставить? Если да то я поставил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь использовать `message.delete()`, что удаляет то сообщение, которое пользователь последним отправил, в данном случае это: -sms.
Вам нужно использовать `bot.delete_message`.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['sms'], commands_prefix='-')
async def sms(message: types.Message):
    await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.message_id)
    await message.answer("️Удалено")
```